# How to insert numbering without changing other variables

Tags: c#

I made this code so far but it's without numbering:

```
int add = files.Length;
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\Windows");

FileInfo[] fiArr = di.GetFiles();

Console.WriteLine("The directory {0} contains the following files:", di.Name);
Console.WriteLine();
foreach (FileInfo f in fiArr) {
    Console.WriteLine(" {0} ({1}) ", f.Name, f.Length);
}
Console.WriteLine();
Console.ReadLine();

PressEnter();
Console.Clear();
```

i want the output to be like this:

Files in:

```
C:\Windows
1. explorer.exe (2871808)
2. ODBC.ini (376)
3. winhlp32.exe (9728)
...
```

Comment: Use a `for` loop instead of `foreach` and use the loop variable in your output.

Comment: Files in: C:\Windows
1. explorer.exe (2871808)
2. ODBC.ini (376)
3. winhlp32.exe (9728)
...

Comment: i want the output to be like that only when i use the for loop the files get repeated all the time..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
int i = 1;
foreach (FileInfo f in fiArr)
{
   Console.WriteLine("{0}. {1} ({2}) ",i , f.Name, f.Length);
   i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a count variable. You might want to name it `i` since that's a common name for it. Initialize it outside the loop. In your case, initializing it with `1` would make most sense.

Then, in your loop, in the `WriteLine()` call, add a new placeholder to the beginning of the format string and insert your count variable as the first argument after the format string. After the call, increment the variable using the `++` operator.

You could also initialize it with `0` outside and increment it at the beginning of each loop. Whatever you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Using LINQ

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\Windows");

FileInfo[] fiArr = di.GetFiles();

Console.WriteLine("The directory {0} contains the following files: {1}"
        , di.Name
        , String.Join(
            " ", 
            fiArr.Select(
                (x, index) => String.Format(
                                "{0}. {1} ({2})"
                                , index+1
                                , x.Name
                                , x.Length
                            )
           )
        ) 
    );

Console.ReadKey();
Console.Clear();
```

Comment: Nice. btw, from .NET 4.0 onwards, the ToArray() is redundant, as Join supports `IEnumerable<string>` as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop instead of `foreach`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fiArr.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i + 1 + ". " + fiArr[i].Name + " (" + ffiArr[i].Length + ")");
    // ...
```